# As much as "you" or "you do"

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, comparisons

I came across this sentence in a blog.. "You'll receive no more than 1-2 emails per week, as we hate spam just as much as you. "

While I appreciate the sentiment, i can't help but wonder if they hate me!
So here's my question : Is this sentence correct? To me, it seems like it should be "we hate spam just as much as you DO".

In the third person though, there are two different forms, owing to two different words for the subject pronoun and object pronoun (unlike "you")
1."we hate spam just as much as SHE". (girl + bloggers hate spam)
2."we hate spam just as much as HER". (bloggers hate girl + spam)

Since this is not the case with "you", should there absolutely be a "do" at the end of the sentence, or are we supposed to just understand it based on context? 
Or is "we hate spam just as much as you" the actual right way of conveying that they hate spam, making me completely wrong (and a little paranoid)?

Comment: Yes, based on context the meaning is pretty clear to native speaker and yes, "we hate spam just as much as we hate you" would be more correct and explicit.

Comment: I think you are right that they are saying they hate you just as much as they have spam.  What a terrible company.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall So you're saying, having a "do" is not necessary, IF the context is clear. If a certain shady character were saying the same thing, and it were possible for us to derive either meaning, we'd want him to make it more explicit.

Comment: Yes. But you could say that about any ambiguous statement :)

Comment: Grammatically speaking the *do* is **required**. However, it is so common and better-sounding to drop the *do* so as not to appear overly-academic. It works in informal and semi-formal writing, including e-mail and routine business correspondence. No need to worry, or you may be thought to be pedantic.

Comment: "We hate spam just as much as her" could very well be intended to mean "We hate spam just as much as she does". Pullum advises that "She was taller than him" sounds less 'ridiculously stuffy' than the prescriptively required "She was taller than he". However, I'd aim for clarity as top priority.

Comment: I faced a similar question regarding the lyrics of The Vaccines: If You Wanna. It says "friends I do not like as much as you". Is it "friends I do not like as much as I like you" or "friends I do not like as much as you like them"? If I understand correctly, it's probably the former, solely because the latter meaning would need another "do" at the end :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three rules of writing for the web, in order of priority, are:

1. Keep it accessible.
2. Keep it clear. Never force the reader to stop and think.
3. Keep it short.

So the question is: did you have to stop and think about whether they hate you or spam? If you did, even for a nano-second, then *you do* is better, because it clears up the ambiguity (Rule 2).  Otherwise, *you* is better because it's shorter (Rule 3).

As for grammaticality, *as much as you* and *as much as you do* are both acceptable.

The rule you cite about writing *as much as she* rather than *as much as her* is, to say the least, debatable. It's a holdover from the 18th century fashion for making formal writing sound more like Latin. It may be appropriate to follow this rule in some very formal texts, but not in a blog.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically speaking, the do is necessary. I disagree that inclusion of the 'do' is academic. It avoids ambiguity, and is good grammar (which is important if your / the email's audience includes people who would care about such things). Without the 'do', the sentence would be deemed 'colloquial'.

Comment: I don't think that's true. There's no requirement to restate the verb in comparisons. Compare "Bob's as tall as Ada" "I ate more than Maria", "My elephant's bigger than yours" These are in no way ungrammatical. They are clunky the other way round: "Bob's as tall as Ada is", "I ate more than Maria ate", "My elephants bigger than yours is". Even in formal writing... compare "*The FTSE has consistently fared better than the Dow Jones*" versus "*The FTSE has consistently fared better than the Dow Jones has*"